# How to manipulate "add media" pop-up

Tags: theme-development, media

Is there any way to add your own button next to "insert into post" button on the "add media" pop-up? I would like the button to add my own shortcode tags around the inserted image.

The desired result:

```
[myshortcode]<a href="link"><img scr="img.jpg" /></a>[/myshortcode]
```

instead of just:

```
<a href="link"><img scr="img.jpg" /></a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no easy way to add a new button at present, however the "image_send_to_editor" filter will let you modify the HTML that is returned for the post insertion.